# Accessing a folder by guid in Sharepoint 2013(Odata)

Tags: sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to extract a video that is embedded into a list item in our Sharepoint API.  An example of the data I have is:

```
site=218a5f362d1241418a939d5c302507a0&amp;web=425c1c9cf7e3406d9a0d2cc5f28ec9e0&amp;folder=25abed4de9624c9ca264e39f3de7f747
```

I'm assuming I can access the folder by the GUID provided, but I don't see to be able to do so?  How can I access the file that this is pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to process each Id in order to get the associate object.

To get the web, you can use :

```
/_api/web/webs?$filter=ID eq guid'**your_web_guid**'
```

Now, you have the web url. You can get your list :

```
your_web_url/_api/Web/Lists(guid'**your_list_guid**')
```

You got the list title. Then you can get the list of all the folders in your list :

```
your_web_url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('**your_list_title**')/items?$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId, '0x0120')
```

Search the guid of your folder in the results and your job is done.

Comment: I'm afraid `/_api/web/webs?$filter=ID eq guid'**your_web_guid**'` won't work if the web is not directly unter the root. It will only return the direct child webs. You would need something like Site.AllWebs, but that property is not exposed in the REST interface, as far as I know.